# Kendo grid disable column to edit

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Based on this [link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-generate-model-from-data) I generate the dataSource model based on the dynamic data I have in the grid. Now I wanted to disable column `Name` from edit. Usually I just set `name: { editable: false, nullable: true }` but here a bit different any idea how to achieve this?

2nd question - How do I reload the grid? I cannot call `$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();`. It wont reload the grid.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IcUPOdon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the property if it equals "Name" set editable to false:

```
fields[property] = {
  type: "string",
  editable: property === 'Name' ? false : true,     
  validation: {
    required: true
  }
}
```

[Disable editable](https://dojo.telerik.com/IDALARaj)

Did you try to refresh grid?

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.refresh();
```

[Kendo grid refresh](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/refresh)

**EDIT:**

You can add data to grid by adding it in `dataSource`, in that case you don't need to refresh grid:

```
  grid.dataSource.add(
    {
      "Name": "Test",
        "level_1": 44,
        "level_2": 23
    }
  );
```

Example: [Add item to grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/OXeluPOH)

Comment: yes, I try `grid.refresh()` but seem the grid still not refreshing. it's because it inside the function?

Comment: what do you mean by reloading grid? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: basically what I want to achieve is same in [this link](https://dojo.telerik.com/IcUPOdon/7).. Once I enter a value in the textbox, then I click `Add into Grid` button, an ajax function will be call to add the value into the grid. If return success I want the grid refresh/reloading and new the value that insert will be display in the grid.
That's what I mean currently I try `grid.refresh()` and it not working.

Comment: thank you for your help. Quick question any idea how to change field name? `title`